# How to create a bookmark for a url and reopen the bookmark in chrome using TestCafe automation

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a scenario where I need to bookmark my report url and then changed the user permission to not to allow to view the report. If the same user try to open the saved bookmark url he should not be allowed. I just need help in how to bookmark a url and reopen it back using testcafe automation in Angular15. Example URL to bookMark.

> https://localhost:4200/cc/dashboard/8155fc36-1111-4ad4-ab11-1331e756ef33/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestCafe is an end-to-end testing solution for websites. As far as I understand, you want to manipulate the browser interface. It's not possible to do so in TestCafe.
As far as I know, adding any URL to bookmarks and opening this URL from bookmarks won't affect your site's behavior. If you just want to get the report URL from the test, you can use the `eval` method:

```js
const location = await t.eval(() => window.location);
```

Then, you can use the received URL anywhere, including navigation to this URL after changing the role.